# Get place number of div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have following slider code in html;

```
<div class="carousel-inner" style="position: relative;">

<div class="item">
    <img src="forsidebanner_gf39.jpg" alt="">
    <a class="overlay" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; width: 101.4%; height: 103.31491712707%;" href="domain.com" title="">
    </a>
</div>
<div class="item active">
    <img src="forsidebanner_50fifty_somvistpaafarmen.jpg" alt="">
    <a class="overlay" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; width: 100.8%; height: 102.76243093923%;" href="domain.com/one.html" title="">
    </a>
</div>
```

What I want to achieve is to console log the div number of class "item" so for example if clicked on image 1 of parent class "item" it will print 1, and if click on second image it will print 2.

I tried this code but its printing only 1

```
$(".item").click(function(){
var numitem = $(this).length;
    console.log(numitem);

});
```

This is the demo link -> https://jsfiddle.net/ru44voeq/
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Use jquery `.index()`

Comment: works without overlays: https://jsfiddle.net/81g5kh9e/2/

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio thanks your code works, but the issue is that I am not able to change the html part. that's why all I need is the jquery script so that I can execute it on editable area of footer and get the result :(

Comment: Can you hide your overlay with jquery, that would solve the problem, example: https://jsfiddle.net/ru44voeq/2/

Comment: @eugensunic yes by hiding overlay it actually works, but on other hand it disables the link. So the slider link will no longer work.

Comment: Since your code is in slider, and only one item should be shown in one moment, inside container... I actually don't understand why index() doesn't work, without removing of overlays? You should use selector: $(".item a") and get .item index with: $(this).closest('.item').index();

Comment: And, since you use bootstrap carousel, if i am right, here is completely functional example: https://jsfiddle.net/ru44voeq/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem were the overlays. Because of that you could not retrieve the index of the clicked element. Since you can not hide them by removing the html the jquery then took care of that.

Because the overlays were hidden, you can not navigate to your URL. By retrieving the URL attribute

`window.location.href = $(this).find(".overlay").attr("href");`

from the overlay which is shown again that is made possible and the page is shown.

Full jquery code and example,

fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/eugensunic/ru44voeq/3/

```
$(".overlay").hide();
$(".item").click(function(){

    var numitem = $(this).index()+1;
    $(".overlay").show();
    window.location.href = $(this).find(".overlay").attr("href");
    alert(numitem);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `index()` function work but the problem you have is the `style` of `overlays` like **@GrafiCode Studio** mentioned in comment, so when removing the `style` the link will not work, that true.

Try this solution that copy the `img` tag and remove the original and append the copy of the `img` to the link, it work see the code bellow.

```js
//Restructuring the HTML code on ready 
$(".carousel-inner").find('.item').each(function(){
  //make a copy of img
  var img = $(this).find('img').clone(true);

  //remove image
  $(this).find('img').remove();

  //append copy to the link
  $(this).find('a').removeAttr('style').html(img);    
});

//Handle the click event
$(".item").click(function(){
    var numitem = $(this).index()+1;
    alert(numitem);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="carousel-inner" style="position: relative;">

    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://web.ccpgamescdn.com/newssystem/media/67432/1/100_-Twitter.jpg" alt="">
            <a class="overlay" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; width: 101.4%; height: 103.31491712707%;" href="domain.com" title="">
            </a>
            </div>
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="http://www.elcomcms.com/Images/UserUploadedImages/664/facebookicon_100x100.jpg" alt="">


                <a class="overlay" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; width: 100.8%; height: 102.76243093923%;" href="domain.com/one.html" title="">
                </a>
                </div>

        </div>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You can use inArray function to solve this. Check it out the code below.

```
$(".item").click(function(){

    console.log($.inArray(this,$(".item")));

});
```

Doing this, you will add to every item the click event. The function inArray works with a element on the first parameter, on this case the item, and a list of elements on the second parameter, this function will return the index of the item on the given array.

Answer (score -1):

You are setting a click listener to each of the items.

When the callback function gets executed the context (what `this` refers to) is the clicked element, the node itself.

Then you call the jQuery function on the node with `$(this)` which returns you a jQuery element, with only that node in it.That's why `length` is 1.

If you want to get the number of the `.item` you should do something like:

```
var items = $('.item')
items.click(function (){
    .....
    items.length //number of items
    $(this).index() //index of the node in its parent, not relative to the `.items`
    var itemIndex = $.inArray(this, items) //as suggested by @Franklin Satler
})
```

The [docs](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) say:

> Search for a specified value within an array and return its index (or -1 if not found).